# Android can not call Kotlin code in Java code cause when using kotlin enum in companion

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I got a kotlin class:

```kotlin
class KotlinClass(val enum: CompanionEnum) {

    companion object {
        enum class CompanionEnum(val value: String) {
            ENUM_1("AAAA"),
            ENUM_2("BBBB"),
        }
    }

    fun doSomething() {
        print( enum.value)
    }
}
```

And I can use this class in kotlin code like this, and this works fine:

```kotlin
KotlinClass(KotlinClass.Companion.CompanionEnum.ENUM_1).doSomething()
```

But I can't use this kotlin code in Java code:

```java
new KotlinClass(KotlinClass.Companion.CompanionEnum.ENUM_1).doSomething();
```

`Android Studio` always tips me `Expected class or package`:

[image]

How to use this Kotlin class in Java code without changing the kotlin code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why is that, probably something related to package naming conflicts within the bytecode generated by the kotlin code but I was able to use the Kotlin code in Java by using an import that kind of avoids this confusion. Try it:

```
import com.yourpackage.KotlinClass.Companion.CompanionEnum;

public class test {
    public void testMethod() {
       new KotlinClass(CompanionEnum.ENUM_1).doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: This's exactly the answer, I tried and it works fine.

Comment: glad I could help :)